# Subtract of two char into rax

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

When I do :

```
endnf:
    add al, BYTE[rdi]
    sub al, BYTE[rsi]
    jmp end
```

When BYTE[rdi] = 116 and BYTE[rsi] = 122 the result is 250 instead of -6 because al = sizeof(char)

So I tried :

```
endnf:
    add rax, BYTE[rdi]
    sub rax, BYTE[rdi]
    jmp end
```

But I doesn't work :

```
nasm -f elf64 strcmp.s                            16:31:07
strcmp.s:24: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

What should I do to subtract rdi[0] and rsi[0] ?

Comment: `250` is `-6` in 8 bits two's complement. If you want a bigger result, sign extend it such as `movsx rax, al`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error stems from the fact that you should have written `... rax, qword ptr [...]` to have operands of matching size.

I don't get why you wrote an `add` instruction to fetch the value at [rdi].

The simplest solution is:

```
mov   al, [rdi]
sub   al, [rsi]
movsx rax, al
```

If you wrote the next lines, you would have gotten the same result. It's silly but it does leave the same result in AL which as before can be extended to suit your needs.

```
mov   rax, [rdi]
sub   rax, [rsi]
movsx rax, al
```

Comment: The use of `rax,[rdi]` is not the same! That reads four bytes, not just one byte with sign-extension.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis __(1)__ Why would `mov rax,[rdi]` only read __four__ bytes ? __(2)__ I don't see @SepRoland claiming that this instruction reads _one byte with sign-extension_. He just says that the result in RAX at the conclusion of the entire code snippet is the same. This is true. Only the RFLAGS will (most probably) be different!

Comment: Ad (2): No, but there is a difference between reading one byte (which is correct) and then sign-extending it, or reading 8 bytes and more or less discarding the top 7 ones. The 8 byte read might not be permitted.